# Does $\sum^{\infty}_{x=0}\frac{10^x x!}{(5x)^x}$ diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to determine whether this diverges $\sum^{\infty}_{x=0}\frac{10^x x!}{(5x)^x}   $. In an earlier thread, I saw to use stirling's approximation, which in this case leads to:

$(\frac{2}{e})^x \sqrt{2\pi x}   $. The 2/e is less than 0, however with the second term $\sqrt{2\pi x}   $, which is greater than 1, the effect may cancel out. Do I need to do another method?

Comment: $2/e$ is less than $0$?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "$2/e$ is less than $0$".

Answer (score 0):

The general rule that exponentials like $(\frac 2e)^x$ dominate over powers like $\sqrt x$ applies here, so it converges.

Comment: Thanks Ross. What is the general rule? What is the point where it does not dominate?

Comment: Any exponential will dominate over any polynomial, so $a^xx^n \to 0$ for any $a \lt 1$ and any $n$.  Similarly $ a^xx^{-n} \to \infty$ for $a \gt 1$  These should be proved in your course at some point.